# Sugar icing glaze became wet and lost its texture

Tags: icing

We made cookies that we glazed with a simple sugar icing. 
The icing is simple

- confectioners sugar
- skim milk
- almond extract

At first the icing was normal and hardened when dry on the cookie surface, but after a few days, it started to get really wet looking and lost its glazed appearance, like it was melting.  It looked really bad after.

The base of the cookie dough consists of

- approx. 8 - 10 cups cake and pastry flour (extra as needed)
- approx. 3/4 cup sunflower oil
- 12 egg yolks
- 2 cups of milk
- backing powder

I'm just wondering what would cause this?  Is it an interaction with the cookie or the ingredients of the icing or both?

Comment: How are the cookies stored? Sounds like a humidity problem.

Comment: @Catija the were stored at room temperature, in what looks like an aluminum drip pan, only bigger, and it is covered with wax paper, aluminum foil, and a thin cloth on top.  I'd also like to add that it is winter where we live and I thought the air would not hold that much moisture at this time?

Comment: The humidity in a heated, closed house in winter can't get really quite high. Generally you'd put cookies in an airtight container as soon as the icing went hard.